# What do the different values of /sys/kernel/mm/lru_gen/enabled mean?

Tags: linux, sysfs

I wanted to check if the multi-generational LRU was active on my desktop, so I looked at the value of `/sys/kernel/mm/lru_gen/enabled`. It was set to `0x0007`. I felt unsure what to make of this value, so I checked the value on a different device where I knew for sure that I had enabled it since I configured the kernel myself on there, and it gave me the value `0x0001`. What do these two values mean, and what are the expected values if the multi-generational LRU is enabled and disabled? Are there any other valid values for this file?

Comment: The first link from google point me to kernel documentation with good explanation about the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The multi-gen LRU documentation in the kernel](https://docs.kernel.org/next/admin-guide/mm/multigen_lru.html) describes the values as follows:

> | Values | Components |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0x0001 | The main switch for the multi-gen LRU. |
> | 0x0002 | Clearing the accessed bit in leaf page table entries in large batches, when MMU sets it (e.g., on x86). This behavior can theoretically worsen lock contention (mmap_lock). If it is disabled, the multi-gen LRU will suffer a minor performance degradation for workloads that contiguously map hot pages, whose accessed bits can be otherwise cleared by fewer larger batches. |
> | 0x0004 | Clearing the accessed bit in non-leaf page table entries as well, when MMU sets it (e.g., on x86). This behavior was not verified on x86 varieties other than Intel and AMD. If it is disabled, the multi-gen LRU will suffer a negligible performance degradation. |

The values are ored together, so 0x0007 means that all features are enabled, and 0x0001 means that multi-gen LRU is enabled but without clearing the accessed bit in large batches.

Any combination is valid, *i.e.* any value between 0x0000 and 0x0007. The expected value depends on your kernel configuration.